# HTML5 Video tag does not work in any browser

Tags: php, html

This is my code. It is not working. I have embedded this code in php and then tried to implement it in a project.

```
<video width="480" height="400"  controls="controls" style="float:left">
  <source src="admin/short_video.3gp" type="video/3gp">
  <source src="admin/short_video.avi" type="video/avi">
  <source src="admin/short_video.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
  <source src="admin/short_video.ogv" type="video/ogv">
  <source src="admin/short_video.mov" type="video/mov">
  <source src="admin/short_video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Please help. Is there any alternative way to start the video?

Comment: Do you see any errors?

Comment: check that your paths are correct. Also check your admin folder exists and it has requisite permissions.

Comment: Easiest way to check is to look in your browser's *Network* console. You should see a request for at least one of those video files. What does the response look like?

Comment: yes i tried but it doesnot work. it shows the control buttons but video is no playing only sound is playing –

Answer (score 1):

Why the following html fragment does not work in any browser?

```
<video width="480" height="400" controls>    
    <source src="your_path" type="video/mp4">    
</video>
```

Comment: Because ,i use this code and it works in both chrome and internet explorer

Comment: yes i tried but it doesnot work. it shows the control buttons but video is no playing only sound is playing –

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to get only one source tag in your video tag? If you want to provide many video options you can use a select and then from javascript make a lazy load (for avoiding download all the video files)

Comment: yes i tried but it doesnot work. it shows the control buttons but video is no playing only sound is playing

Comment: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) the video tag does not support the following formats: .3gp, .avi and .mov ,

If you upload the video files to your server it would be useful to use an specific supported format (.mp4 or .webm for example)